# saving image upload to folder in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I've success to save the file image to my local folder in my laravel, but i get error when the image view is not found.

this is my `createImage.blade.php`

```
{!!Form::open(['route'=>'lowongan.store', 'method'=>'POST', 'files' => true])!!}
<div class="form-group">
  {!!Form::label('Image Lowongan : ')!!}
  {!!Form::file('imgLoker')!!}
</div>
{!!Form::close()!!}
```

i was setting my `config/filesystem` for destination image where i saved.

```
'disks' => [

        'local' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root'   => public_path('imageLoker'),
        ],
```

And this is my modal, i use Carbon

```
    class Lowongan extends Model {

    protected $table = 'Lowongan';
    protected $fillable = ['judul','imgLoker','deskripsi', 'profilePt','deadline'];

    public function setPathAttribute($path){
        $name = Carbon::now()->second.$path->getClientOriginalName();
        $this->attributes['imgLoker'] = $name;
        \Storage::disk('local')->put($name, \File::get($path));
    }
}
```

for my controller :

```
public function index() {
        $lowongans = Lowongan::all();
        return view('lowongan.index',compact('lowongans'));
}    
public function store(Request $request)
        { Lowongan::create(
                $request->all());
            return "listtt";
        }
```

i get error in this file, my image is not found. This is my `index.blade.php`

```
@foreach($lowongans as $lowongan)
<tr>
  <td>
    <img src="imageLoker/{{$lowongan->imgLoker}}" alt="" />
  </td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

[image]

Comment: try this `<?php echo asset('imageLoker/'.$lowongan->imgLoker); ?>`

Comment: also, is there any message in the developer console?

Comment: i was try but its not show the image but like that : `http://localhost:8000/imageLoker/C:\xampp\tmp\phpC23F.tmp` @Karan

Comment: i get error : `http://localhost:8000/imageLoker/ 404 (Not Found)` @naneri

Comment: what info `imgLocker` contain? Seems you are saving temporary file path into database. You should save file name those uploaded into `imgLoker` directory.